# Splashscreen for embedded Linux

Tags: startup, embedded, x-server, bootsplash

Is it possible to get a normal splashscreen for Linux?
I'm trying to show a logo before my application is autostarted with Linux, I've activated this option in kernel, the logo comes after ca. 2 seconds and is shown till X-server is started, but the X-server needs almost 3-4 seconds to start, then my application needs almost 2 seconds, so you can see a blank scree for 5-6 seconds, it looks really annoying. I know there are 3 options to show splashcreen with Linux:

1. U-boot and patch to keep it in kernel, works fast but should have
   the same problem and needs much more efforts.
2. Linux kernel - that's my option at the moment.
3. init.d script with fbi to show the logo - starts later and has the same problem, I've already tried it.

Is there any additional options to keep the logo till application is started and bypass all these things from the X-server?

Comment: May I add one more option? Exclude bulky X at all, instead go for framebuffer. Eliminating need to start X, it allows you for smooth transition from one step to another. So far my usual flow is: uboot -> psplash -> when all the loading is finished, turn off psplash and start UI. For additional info, try googling "framebuffer" and "directfb" to see if it's a viable option for you.

Comment: Yes, it seems to be a good decision, but I'm using webkigtk in my application, so I should rebuild gtk with FB support, searching the web gives me pretty bad chances to make it possible :(